# Adding words to Google Input Dictionary

Tags: ime

How do I add words to my user dictionary in Google Japanese Input?

I've tried the obvious - right click, Add Word - and the word then shows up in my User Dictionary ... but then it doesn't actually show up in my list of possible kanji.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in google chrome extension for input tools..?

Answer (score 2):

Click on gear icon > Manage Macros > write "macro text" in English > write your "macro target" as you want macro text to be converted to.

For detailed info, see this: 
https://www.google.co.in/inputtools/windows/macros.html

Answer (score 1):

Oh geez, it's been a while. I actually solved the problem a while back but forgot to update it.

First, the obvious method does in fact work. The problem is that there's actually *two* ways to enter kanji from romaji from the IME prompt, and I only knew about one of them at the time of writing. Namely, you can hit Tab to select from direct interpretations, *or* you can hit *space* to engage the full engine, including online suggestions, the *kaomoji* index, and any custom words you've added to your dictionary. They won't show up in the tab-completion menu, though, which is what was confusing me.